# C# Facebook SDK Authorization Flow- how to redirect back to page?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have an app that'll be used in a Facebook page tab for which I'll be requesting basic permissions.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 with ASP.NET 3.5.

I'm using the following Action Attributes:

```
[HttpPost]
[CanvasAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index(string signed_request)
{
    ViewData["section"] = "post";
    FacebookPageModel page = new FacebookPageModel();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signed_request))
    {
        string signedRequest = Request.Form["signed_request"];
        var DecodedSignedRequest = 
            FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(
             ((FacebookConfigurationSection)   
                ConfigurationManager
                    .GetSection("facebookSettings"))
                    .AppSecret, 
            signed_request);
        var SignedRequestData = DecodedSignedRequest.Data;
        var RawRequestData = (IDictionary<string, object>)SignedRequestData;
        // ok, start getting the data
        page.user_id = FacebookWebContext.Current.UserId.ToString();
        if (RawRequestData.ContainsKey("page") == true)
        {
            Facebook.JsonObject RawPageData = 
                (Facebook.JsonObject)RawRequestData["page"];
            if (RawPageData.ContainsKey("liked") == true)
            {
                page.UserLikesThisPage = (bool)RawPageData["liked"];
            }
        }

        if (RawRequestData.ContainsKey("app_data") == true)
        {
            page.app_data = RawRequestData["app_data"].ToString();                    
        }
    }
    return View(page);
}

public class FacebookPageModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> SignedRequestParameters { get; set; }
    public bool UserLikesThisPage { get; set; }
    public string app_data { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TwitterSearchResultsModel> tweets { get; set; }
}
```

web.config:

```
<facebookSettings 
    appId="221731264504206" 
    appSecret="blah-blah-blah" 
    canvasUrl="http://url-of-canvas-page-tab/" 
    canvasPage="http://url-of-canvas-page-tab/" />
```

Calling CanvasAuthorize without any other parameters seems to request Basic permissions, which is what I want.  The problem is that after clicking Allow, the forward url is sending me to the user's profile page, not to my page tab.

How do I configure my app to forward the user back to the calling page after Allowing the requested permissions?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [CanvasAuthorize] has some additional parameters I can use:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(ReturnUrlPath="enter-url-here")]
```

I know it is strange I didn't know this, since C# Facebook SDK is so well documented. :^)

But it is Free, so who am I to complain, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CanvasAuthorize is not meant for tabs but rather for canvas applications only.

Comment: Is there another way to test whether a person has authorized your Facebook Page Tab?